# Why PWA cannot be installed on PC

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

[Fizza](https://fizza.az). I have added PWA instructions as described. On mobile adding to home screen works as expected, but on PCs it does nothing though you click to `install`. There is no debuggable info logged to console either.

Comment: Which browser? Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: Chrome. Can you please take a look at the link? https://fizza.az

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: sorry didn't understand

Comment: I checked. Looks like it does pass as a valid PWA. But it does not install for me also. Sorry, I'm not sure why. Perhaps someone else has seen this before.

Comment: This may be a bug I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the issue. My icon images in `manifest.json` did not match the exact dimensions. Error was visible in Chrome Canary. Create your manifest and icons using 3rd party manifest generators like https://app-manifest.firebaseapp.com/